# Remove div class if display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know if there is a way to remove a class when that class is marked with *display: none;*. Basically, I would like to prevent it from loading.

Is it possible to do it using JQuery?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, jquery can do that. Search for selecting elements  by css attributes.

Comment: @MrGlass I think this attribute doesn't have a `class`, only `CSS`, is it right ?

Comment: This sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried, what your expected outcome is, and what problems you are encountering? Be specific and include actual code examples. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some guidance here.

Comment: *I would like to prevent it from loading.* Whaa?  The markup already exists in the DOM.  It's "loaded"

Comment: If the element has `display: none` via a style asssignment or a class assignment, you still can search/select by css attribute.

Comment: How would you know what class to remove that has the display none?

Comment: Trying to remove html from the page all together?  You can remove it using javascript but you should remove the html before it gets sent to client side browsers.  Edit the server side files instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.class-you-want-to-remove:hidden').removeClass('class-you-want-to-remove');
```

https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: That would remove any hidden element. If i understood him right he only wants to remove elements with that class so it should be $('class-you-want-to-remove:hidden').removeClass('class-you-want-to-remove');

Comment: Correct, I just read his question again. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use hide() method in jQuery to hide the blocks under that class.

```
$(".classname").hide();
```

Similarly you use show() method to show the blocks under that class.

```
$(".classname").show();
```